# Converting Native Promise to JQuery's Promise( For IE )

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am currently heavily dependent on Native "Promise" object in Javascript for doing AJAX Calls. But, as mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and after my Test in IE11, Native Promises don't work in IE.

Now, the solution is to use JQuery's Promises, But i am unable to make it work.
Please find the below code for Native Promise:( Works in all Browsers except IE )

```
var getJSON = function (url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log(window.location);
        console.log(window.location.origin);
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.responseType = 'application/json';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
};

getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Success");           
}, function (status) { //error detection....
    console.log(status);
    alert('Something went wrong.');
});*/
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work

```
 var promise = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }
}).done(function (data){
    console.log(data);  
});
```

I think we have to use the Deferred Object but unable to figure out !!
Note: Can't use PolyFill or BlueBird due to lack of Node.js 
Thanks

Comment: [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/)

Comment: Don't. You won't be happy with jQuery. Use a proper polyfill instead.

Comment: If you've written a lot of code for native promises, it would be much easier to get a polyfill for native promises.  jQuery promises (at least before 3.0) are very non-standard in both syntax and behavior.  A plain polyfill or an enhanced polyfill such as Bluebird will work great for you without changing any of your existing code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks a Lot. But, for implementing PolyFill, i need to have Node.js which i don't have . So, that's why i was inclined towards jQuery Promises. Any normal example will be good.

Comment: You can get a promise polyfill for the browser just fine.  You don't need node.js.  node.js has nothing to do with this.  Just load Bluebird or any other suitable polyfill into your webpage and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh i didn't know about that. I will look into it and get back. Thanks a Lot

Comment: Thanks!! The Promise issue is solved, but i am getting CORS issue with IE11( which is again working perfectly in Chrome!!!) I don't know why IE can't learn from Chrome!!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var p = $.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
    }
});
// use p.then()
```

Note: 
jQuery has a `$.JSON()` function directly.

Also, have a look at [Promise-Polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) if you just want promises!